# Capitalising Words in Parentheses?

Tags: grammar, punctuation, capitalization, parentheses

Should the words inside a set of parentheses be capitalised?

For example:

> ... usually read for personal
>   enjoyment (**R**ecreation) or ...

or

> ... usually read for personal
>   enjoyment (**r**ecreation) or ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only need capitalize a [parenthesis](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/parenthesis) if it is a complete sentence terminating with a period or full stop. Thus:

> ... usually read for personal enjoyment (recreation) or ...

Comment: Would it be *wrong*, however, to capitalise the words inside the sentence?

Comment: @JFW: Apologies for the belated response. You may decide to capitalize any words within a parenthetic sentence for any stylistic reason, and that would not be deemed wrong. Also, there may be words that have to be capitalized, e.g. proper nouns, song titles, etc. The same rules of capitalization in sentences hold for parenthetic ones, as well. I hope this answers your question.

Answer (score 3):

There is no need to capitalize words in parentheses.

> Where we were going (it was not open for discussion) was kept secret from us.